# Streaming MJPG with Authentication

Tags: authentication, video-streaming, mjpeg

I have an MJPG stream I need to embed in a web page. It requires authentication to view, but I do not necessarily want to prompt the user when they view the page.

So, is there a MJPG streamer (built into a browser or Java/Flash based) that supports passing the required credentials to the MJPG stream to authenticate?

The only way I would know how to do that would be to pass the username and password in the URL like this: `http://username:password@[ip address]/`. This doesn't work, unfortunately.

Comment: Do you even have permission (from those authoring/hosting the stream) to embed it on your page? What sort of authentication scheme is in use? (e.g: HTTP Basic/Digest, cookie-based, SSL Client cert, etc).

Comment: Yes, this is an internal application for a company. The username and password is shared throughout the entire company because the streaming server needs one set. I am adding another login (using Active Directory) to log what user looks at what video feed, but I don't want to require the user to login to the dashboard *and* all of the video feeds, which is why I want to pass the username and password in. The authentication is just HTTP Basic. Turns out, passing the username and password as I specified works in all browsers *but* IE, which is what is used by all employees. It's always IE. :|

Comment: Tried "Chrome Frame"? It allows you to have a frame of content that is rendered using Google Chrome within IE. It only works on content that 'advertises' needing Chrome Frame so it wouldn't affect anything else users do.

Comment: The problem is, I don't really want the hassle of deploying Chrome frame to the entire department. Believe me, I would *love* for that to happen, unfortunately this one project isn't enough for IT to do that.

Comment: @AndrewM Have you ever solved this problem?

Comment: Yes-- a Java app is now used to stream the MJPEG instead of letting the browser do it.